# Add observer without using selector

Tags: swift, observer-pattern

I need to add observes in my project, but since the manager that I work with, doesn't let me to use @objc in the functions, is there anyway that I can use this function without using @objc?

```
   func createObservers() {
      NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(self.updatedata(notification:)),
                                             name: Notification.Name(rawValue: updateNotificationKey), object: nil)

    }

   @objc dynamic func updatedata(notification: NSNotification) {
         updateDataIcon()
     }
```

Your help will be appreciated.

Comment: Why on earth aren't you allowed to use `@objc`?

Comment: I don't know :) this is a condition to approve pull request

Comment: This method requires an @objc func.  There is no way around it and no reason to avoid it.  Your only other option is to use [addObserver(forName:object:queue:using:)](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/notificationcenter/1411723-addobserver) or [publisher(for:object:)](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/notificationcenter/3329353-publisher) if you are in iOS 13.

Comment: When I run into things like this, I search the entire codebase for other usages -- then you can see the preferred way the team uses various frameworks.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can use this with the inline block

```
NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(forName:  Notification.Name(rawValue: updateNotificationKey) , object: nil, queue: .main) { [weak self] notification in 
   // to do 
}
```

Comment: It's worth noting that unlike `addObserver(_:selector:name:object:)`, this API (the one without `@objc`) is documented to not automatically unregister. You have to manually unregister it by calling any of the `removeObserver` APIs before the object it specifies is deallocated.